# When clicking on a tag in SO allow display of opportunities within that tag

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

It would be a small feature request, not urgent, but maybe one day that if you click a tag it shows potential jobs for that tag?

Answer (score 1):

Hover over a tag and if there are any related jobs, you'll see a 'Job' link. Click that to get a list of related jobs.

This is what we have right now. Deeper integrations for jobs related tags is on our roadmap so I'm setting this to deferred.

[image]